# how to remove greendroid's homebutton

Tags: android, android-actionbar, greendroid, home-button

I'm using **greendroid** as a library in order to implement an action bar. I have a problem about how to remove the **home button** and customize the location of buttons.For example, I want to place the `Add` button first.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8kgbp[1](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8kgbp)

In the picture above, I plan to arrange the `Compose` button to be displayed first, but I have problems on how to do it. Anyone know how to arrange the order of greendroid's action bar?